# Best way to narrow down source of high-CPU usage/load times on website?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress website that has a decent amount of traffic, both guests and logged-in users. (Logged in users not served cache pages). I use WP Super Cache.
The site is very dynamic (main purpose is file downloading, rating, sharing, Buddypress section, etc.) It's quite large and active at all times.

I've taken an initiative on optimizing the basics of the site as best I can (much of it is run by a custom-written plugin done by myself) but I use a few third-party plugins as well (the aforementioned Buddypress, for example)

Anyway.

At any given time the site runs fine. But at "high traffic times" (weekends, etc) **the site is constantly at >100% CPU usage and is very, very slow.**

To add to the confusion, at similar "high traffic times" the site load is not necessarily high at all. It seems to come and go, but is *typically* associated with high volume of traffic.

Point is, it's quite sporadic. And can last for a few minutes to hours to maybe the entire day is just "high" CPU usage.

Before I throw in the towel and just ask my host to up my CPU power, I'd like to try to narrow it down. How can I do this? I'm not too adept with server maintenance, but hypothetically for example, maybe I can tell phpmyadmin to "log all queries for the next 30 minutes and rank them by number of times they've run and just how much CPU impact they've caused" etc. Whether or not that's a "thing" idk but that's what I'm asking here - **what can I try to attempt to figure out the source of these slowdowns?**

(I have tried disabling plugins here and there, but it's hard to do with how dynamic and mashed together the plugins are with each other. Disabling one thing kinda interferes with something else or worse.)

(I've also used plugins like Query Monitor and gone around the site optimizing and fixing any "slow queries" I've found, well, as much as I can. It's not the same, though. This issue happens on a LIVE site, with large traffic. Me on a test installation or as a single user is not the same environment. Besides, I may just not happen across the queries that are causing the issue.)

Running of "htop" just in case useful info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkeRN.png

Comment: If you have shell access to your server and it's Linux or some other UNIX derivative, you can use the `top` command to show which processes are hogging the cpu, and how much memory they use.  Or, you can install the `htop` program which will tell you more about RAM usage. Also: some cloud vendors offer "burstable" virtual machines. If they get hammered by continuous user load for more than a few minutes, the vendor throttles them back and they slow down. That way the vendor can sell more virtual machines. Burstable instances are cheap, but they may be unsuitable for your workload.

Comment: One other suggestion: try Cloudflare's free tier for their content delivery network. It should cut your server workload and help keep cybercreeps away.

Comment: @O.Jones thanks - I have and have had Cloudflare activated for years, that does well serving cached files but in terms of this it's not really effective, it's more of a mysql thing - running `htop` for example, it shows "mysql" as using the most (https://i.imgur.com/8eqDw4P.png) but this isn't really too helpful

Comment: this is a shot in the dark, but we recently ran into a similar issue (on the surface anyway). mysql was maxing out  our CPU, despite having a proxy page cache layer enabled and we couldn't figure out where the inefficient queries were. google have rather recently changed their indexing strategy for mobile, and embarked on a giant recrawl, with all kinds of derived querystrings which bypassed our cache rules. It looked like a DDOS at first, have look at your server request logs to see what kind of queries are coming in, and if they make sense (are real pages), and this went on for several days.

Comment: @baku that definitely sounds almost identical, thanks, this has been going on for 2+ years though on and off so unlikely due to this, but will check anyway. Could end up just being the CPU isn't capable of handling typical site load

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Hi and thank you. Sorry I can't give all info, I'd need my server tech who has all the necessary logins and tough to get in touch with right now. Sorry if not formatted best way, here is query results: https://pastebin.com/pWEKdDnq || Also I do not have access to MySQLTuner but have this from phpmyadmin if helpful: https://i.imgur.com/KuojNG5.png || And finally, server CPU: 2x3.0 GHz+, 8GB RAM Ram doesn't seem to be issue: https://i.imgur.com/8eqDw4P.png

Comment: Thank you for your postings.  Analysis in process.  Do you have flexibility to use Skype Talk?  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.  We are in UTC -6 hrs time zone.  Birmingham, AL  USA

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=600  # from 200 to enable higher IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 226691
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4  # from 1 to reduce mutex contention
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G  # from 128M to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads RPS of 297
innodb_log_file_size=64M  # from 5M for ~ 1 hr before log rotation
```

These configuration changes should expedite query completion.  There are several more opportunities to improve performance.

Observation, 
Slow_queries average 165 RPhr and can usually be corrected with appropriate indexes.
Your log is already active and would be used to summarize with mysqldumpslow -s t to identify most used to be corrected first.

For additional assistance, get in touch, please.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help, i'm going to pass this onto my server guy with root access and will report back if i notice any changes